# Some way to ensure data integrity without compiling RPG with file-level check?

Tags: db2, rpg

Some members on our team write/maintain RPG programs - they share a db2 database, consisting of tables both journaled and not journaled.

If we compile with level-check, then even if we're just adding a new column to a table, then any RPG programs using that table will throw a run-time error.

If we compile *without* level check, then if an RPG program is using non-journaled tables, and we remove a relevant column from one of those tables, then the RPG program might insert into a non-journaled table, then fail to insert into the second (modified) table, thereby leaving orphaned data (as we cannot use transactions, as the tables are not journaled).

What we want is to not have to recompile anything when just adding a column (or increasing a column's size, etc.) - but without risking data integrity.

Is there any way by which we could accomplish this?

Comment: A solution can be access to file with SQL, so when you select or update a file with a new coloumn, or a deleted (not used in the program) the program still works. You can't prevent error from changing column size or type. And remember, if you choose SQLRPGLE use `Select FIELD1, FIELD2...` instead of `Select *` to prevent SQL Fails

Answer (score 3):

> What we want is to not have to recompile anything when just adding a column (or increasing a column's size, etc.) - but without risking data integrity.

Adding a column is easy, changing the size is another story...

What you need is a layer that separates your RPG programs from the physical data layout.

Simply do two things

1. Define all LF with an explicit format
2. Have all your RPG programs access via a LF, instead of accessing via the PF.

so you might have

```
A* My Physical file
A                                      UNIQUE  
A          R MYPFR                     
A            MYKEY          3A         COLHDG('Key Field')
A            FLD1          10A         COLHDG('field 1')
A            FLD2          15A         COLHDG('field 2')
A            FLD3          20A         COLHDG('field 3')
A          K MYKEY
```

In your logicals, explicitly list the fields included...

```
A                                      UNIQUE  
A          R MYLFR                     PFILE(MYPF)
A            MYKEY          
A            FLD1          
A            FLD2          
A            FLD3          
A          K FLD1
```

What you **do not** want have is a LF that auto-magically uses the PF format.

```
A                                      UNIQUE  
A          R MYLFR                     PFILE(MYPF)
A          K FLD1
```

Now when you add a column to the PF, simply leave all existing LF unchanged.  Thus, their format won't change and your won't need to re-compile any RPG programs **even with level checking turned on**.

You can define new LF that include the new column for use by any RPG programs that need access to the new column.

yes, you'll end up with more logicals overtime.  But as long as the "new" logical uses the same key as an existing, it doesn't take any resources besides a few bytes of disk space.  Since the "new" logical will use the existing access path.  And storing/maintaining the access path is what takes resources on the i.

Moving to this setup isn't all that hard either.

1. Build a new PF with a new name
2. Create a new LF with the existing PF name
3. update existing LF to point to the new PF and to explicitly list the columns.

You can in fact use SQL rather than DDS for step 1, this allows you to use some of the newer SQL-only features of the DB.

The IBM Redbook [Modernizing IBM i Applications from the Database up to the User Interface and Everything in Between](https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg248185.html?Open) details the approach.

But the idea of having the applications work through a LF layer has been around a long, long time.

**Changing the size**
Best way to handle increasing the field size is to add a new version of the column with the larger size and use a DB trigger to keep the the original small version and the larger version in sync.  Of course you'll need to decide what to do when a value is put into the larger column that won't fit in the smaller.

Comment: But when adding a new colum to the PF, don't you have to re-compile the PF *FILE-MBR when using DDS?

Comment: @Radinator  yes, of course.  The logicals get recreated also.  CHGPF (or ALTER TABLE)  handles all that for you in one shot.  The point being that while the PF **(record) format level identifier** will change because of the new fields, the LFs won't. _(If defined with a explicit column list as described)_